# Dependency with different name in manifest

Tags: java, maven, manifest

So I'm telling maven to copy my program's dependencies to a lib folder in the target directory using the maven-dependency-plugin and the maven-jar-plugin to add the classpath (the lib folder) to the manifest.

Now I'm having the problem that the manifest states the the file lib/a-dependency..jar
But my actual program is looking for the lib without the timestamp in its name. Apparently one can resolve this using the mentioned plugins, but I just can't figure out what option would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation of [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) which contains a nice option for that: `<stripVersion>true</stripVersion>`.